# How to run Amplify hosting add command via CLI in a non interactive mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am running the Amplify frontend deployment as part of my CICD pipeline. I have an existing Amplify App which has hosting configured, I just want to integrate it with my new pipeline so that front end deployment is triggered via the pipeline. But when I try to do a amplify publish via codebuild, it says add hosting before publishing. But I have already added hosting for the App manually and also if I try to run amplify add hosting again it expects some inputs from user. I want it to run in a non interactive manner.

Can you tell me how I can achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can associate a git branch with an Amplify environment, then deploy via `git push`.

You should review the Amplify CLI [Headless Mode for CI/CD documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/usage/headless/).

Based on what you describe, you may need to `amplify pull` to sync changes you made via the Amplify Studio webpages with your local environment. Be sure to commit your code before running that command as it will blow away any local changes.

You can use `amplify push -y` to only deploy the backend changes. The -y will bypass prompts. I *think* it even bypasses the "are you sure you want to make destructive changes" warnings, so use with caution.

The `amplify publish` command will deploy the backend, then build and deploy the frontend.

Comment: 1. You cannot integrate all git providers  to host the environment (Azure Pipelines being one). 2. Amplify add hosting does not support headless mode. Refer https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/7486 and https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1090 3. Amplify pull works only for the backend. The author says that he configured hosting manually, but amplify publish does not see it. And that is the problem AWS community keeps ignoring with Amplify.